# Connecting SurfaceTextures to camerax preview usecase in android and receive frames on both

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am working on an app that uses opengl and connects One CameraTexture to the camera like the following:

```
val surfaceProvider = getSurfaceProvider(res)

preview.setSurfaceProvider(surfaceProvider)
```

This is how I init the surfaceProvider

```
private fun getSurfaceProvider(resolution: Size): SurfaceProvider? {
    return SurfaceProvider { request: SurfaceRequest ->
        val r = request.resolution

        cameraTexture!!.setDefaultBufferSize(r.width, r.height)
        effectTexture!!.setDefaultBufferSize(r.width, r.height)

        val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        request.provideSurface(surface,
            executor
        ) {}
    }
}
```

Why do I need to do that?
Because I was trying to get the last frame from the main surfaceTexture as a bitmap, I tried the most recommended two ways which are using glReadPixels and readPixelsFromPBO both pause the stream to get me that bitmap, I want to get 30 bitmaps per seconds to do effects on them and add them to the main frame and I have been stuck at this for a month now, tried all possible solutions.

UPDT#1:
I tried using the ImageAnalysis usecase alongside with the preview usecase and it works but it is slow, I can't convince it to get me more than 10 fps, while the real fps of the preview is very normal, so if I can make the fps of the ImageAnalysis matches that of the preview, this will also help, I read all the docs of the IA, read about the backpressure strategy, tried all the possible options, it is really slow even without doing any kind of heavy processing, just

```
imageProxy.toBitmap() 
fun ImageProxy.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
        val yBuffer = planes[0].buffer // Y
        val vuBuffer = planes[2].buffer // VU

        val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
        val vuSize = vuBuffer.remaining()

        val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + vuSize)

        yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
        vuBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vuSize)

        val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, this.width, this.height, null)
        val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 50, out)
        val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
    }
```

UPDT#2:
Also worth mentioning that I am not using previewView(I am using TextureView instead) so I can't get the bitmap as easy as while using previewView.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the reason you need `Bitmap` is because your algorithm runs on CPU. In that case, `ImageAnalysis` is your best bet.  Using a SurfaceTexture, and downloading a `Bitmap` from GPU may not be as efficient.

`ImageAnalysis` does support 30 or even higher FPS. You can verify it by using an empty analyzer. However, a new `ImageProxy` won't arrive until the previous one is released by the app. Is your format conversion slow?

Comment: well @Xi 张熹 thanks for your answer, you are correct I managed to get it to work with fps =30 and because I convert the ImageProxy to bitmap this took some processing and drop it to 25, the issue is that the image bitmap output of this processing is too late for the main frame because they are drawn in parallel, what I want is to cover each frame with its corresponding mask, this looks terribly hard and looks like it can't be done without getting the frame from the opengl surface the camera is drawing onto.